# PHP random string for every PDO row

Tags: php

I would like to create a random string for every row in my row for the field password - basically its a bulk password generator.

Unfortunately, when I hit the bulk reset button the passwords are reset to all the same string. I would like to have a different random string for each row.

Here is my code:

```
echo '<form method="post" action=""><input type="submit" name="bulk_password_reset" value="Bulk Password Reset" /></form>';
if (isset($_POST['bulk_password_reset'])) {
    $password = generateRandomString();
    while ($result = $sqlUpdate->fetch()) {
        $sqlUpdate = $dbh->prepare("UPDATE $tableName SET password = :password");
        $sqlUpdate-> execute(array(':password'=>$password));
        $sqlUpdate->execute();
        header('Location: su_password_reset.php');
    }
}
```

Here is my random string generator function:

```
//Generate random password
function generateRandomString($length = 10) {
    $characters = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
    $randomString = '';
    for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
        $randomString .= $characters[rand(0, strlen($characters) - 1)];
    }
    return $randomString;
}
```

What am I doing wrong please?

Comment: I can't help but notice that you're not hashing your passwords. Don't write it off as "something minor" or "I'm not storing anything important" or say "I'll do it later". We just had to notify 20k people about a password breach because our wonderful devs subscribed to all of these reasons.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should place `$password = generateRandomString();` inside while loop, and also add `WHERE` condition (I assume, you have `id` in your table) to apply each `UPDATE` to only one row.

```
$sqlSelect = $dbh->query("SELECT id FROM $tableName"); // select ids where you want to change passwords
while ($result = $sqlSelect->fetch()) {
    $password = generateRandomString();
    $sqlUpdate = $dbh->prepare("UPDATE $tableName SET password = :password WHERE id = :id");
    $sqlUpdate->execute(array(':password'=>$password, ':id'=>$result['id']));
    header('Location: su_password_reset.php');
}
```

**UPD** I am no pretty sure about syntax, but this gives you an idea, what you need to do (select id for each row, generate password, then update password for this row only).

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be the problem:

`UPDATE $tableName SET password = :password`

You aren't specifying a `WHERE` clause in your `UPDATE` statement, so it is being applied to the entire column rather than a specific row.

Answer (score 0):

Move this inside your `while` loop:

```
$password = generateRandomString();
```

Currently you're calculating the `$password` just once, then using that value for every row.

Additionally, your `UPDATE` clause isn't restricted to any matching criteria.  Each cycle through the loop, you're updating *every* row in the table.  You need to add a `WHERE` clause to restrict the update to that particular row.

Comment: Hi. It still gives me the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try moving your `$password = generatRandomString()` inside your while loop

```
while ($result = $sqlUpdate->fetch()) {
    $password = generateRandomString();
    $sqlUpdate = $dbh->prepare("UPDATE $tableName SET password = :password");
    $sqlUpdate-> execute(array(':password'=>$password));
    $sqlUpdate->execute();
    header('Location: su_password_reset.php');
}
```

Comment: It still gives me the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$password = generateRandomString(); // Move this inside your while loop
while ($result = $sqlUpdate->fetch())
{
    $password = generateRandomString(); // Like so...
}

// Change function generateRandomString($length = 10) {...} to...
function generateRandomString()
{
    return md5(rand().time());
}
```

And add a where clause to your update query.